# I want to use a smaller array or list to fill a larger array where its size is based on the size of another array

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have a `Map<String, String>` which contains details of 2 Students.

Within this Map there is a date of birth, 1 for each student. I have an array called examsTaken,

`String[] examsTaken = {"Maths1", "Maths1", "Maths2", Maths2};`

I also have an array called `String[] dob = {"13/07/64", "17/08/97", "", ""};`

What I would like to do is take the 2 Date of Births from the Map, and fill the dob array, using what exists in the examsTaken array. i.e I would like my 2 final arrays to look like below

`String[] examsTaken = {"Maths1", "Maths1", "Maths2", Maths2};`

`String[] dob = {"13/07/64", "13/07/64", "17/08/97", "17/08/97"};`

I have tried various different lines of code, however my outputs for my dob array are always either

`String[] dob = {"13/07/64", "17/08/97", "", ""};`

or

`String[] dob = {"", "", "", ""};`

Have tried iterating through the examsTaken array and adding the date of birth from the Map to the dob array, however i cannot get the same amount of date of births in the dob array as examsTaken in that array.

As mentioned above, these are the expected results I would like to see

`String[] examsTaken = {"Maths1", "Maths1", "Maths2", Maths2};`

`String[] dob = {"13/07/64", "13/07/64", "17/08/97", "17/08/97"};`

Comment: Can you show the code you have right now? Personally I am a little lost trying to understand how the arrays relate to the Map<string, string> ?

Comment: I suggest you read up on [Classes and Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html) from the Java Tutorials. Right now you seem to have a bunch of arrays with values all saying something about a student. Why don't you create a `Student` class with properties you need?

Comment: You should really stop doing this. Don't use Arrays/Lists or Maps in this style to collect data belonging together. Create proper classes with the needed fields. This helps you much more to keep related data together.